# gitlab CI/CD: How to enter into a container for testing i.e getting an interactive shell

Tags: gitlab-ci

Like in docker we can enter a container by and have an interactive shell

```
docker-compose exec containername /bin/bash
```

Similary in the `script` in gitlab CI/CD can we enter into it. Like it provides an interactive shell

Eg:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - pwd; ls -al
    HERE I WANT TO HAVE AN INTERACTIVE SHELL SO THAT I CAN CHECK FEW THINGS
```

Comment: Hello, do you use shared runner provided by gitlab or your own? If the runner is yours the procedure is the same as you have mentioned. Otherwise I do not know any ways to debug except for console logging

Comment: I am using shared runner.

Comment: How to create my own runner

Comment: For debugging, I used my own laptop with docker runner. You can find info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to do an small detour here and explain how jobs are working in GitLab CI.

Each job is an encapsulated docker container. The container only executes things you like to be executed within the `script` directive. By default the jobs on shared runners are using a ruby container image.

If you want to check, what you have available within your image, or you want try things out locally. You can do so running a container with this image locally and mounting your project folder into it.

```sh
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/build/project" -w "/build/project" -it <the job image> /bin/bash # or /bin/sh or whatever shell is available in the image.
# -v mounts the current directory int /build/project in your container
# -w changes the working directory to the mounting point
# /bin/bash starts the shell, it might be that there are others within the image
```

If you want to use a different docker image, lets say because you are running some other build tool, you can specify this with the `image` directive like:

```
build:
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - echo "some output"
```

You do have the functionality available within your job, which is provided by the image. As the job will run within a container of that image.

You can even use some tools like https://github.com/firecow/gitlab-ci-local to verify this locally. But in the end those are just docker images, and you can easily recreate the flow on your own.

Comment: Ok. So locally i create the flow in a container (with the same image) on my pc. for this i have to clone the gitlab repo into the build folder also)

Comment: You do not have to clone it into the build folder. You can mount any local folder into your docker image. $(pwd) just resolves to the current path on Linux systems. So it is just a mapping - further information can be gathered from the docker documentation for run and the -v option

Comment: but the problem is i cant have access to `CI_JOB_TOKEN` if i am testing locally

Comment: But you can use a private token, and inject that via `-e` there are a lot of ways. The question is always what you are trying to achieve... And you won't fix your known hosts issue with that ;)

Comment: What about the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/interactive_web_terminal/. I want to test the script commands as it is

Comment: With that you have to setup your own runner infrastructure and you have way more issues ;)